# datetime from timeseries data in multiple columns

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, time-series

I have some timeseries data. It has both time stamps and height data. I am trying to extract time stamp in python acceptable format but have not been able to do so. I can input data as separate values etc, but have not been able to make it in `%y/%m/%d %h:%m:%s` format.

```
#yr  mo dy hr mn  s -        m
2013 12 01 00 00 00 1 5570.251
2013 12 01 00 15 00 1 5570.276
2013 12 01 00 30 00 1 5570.300
2013 12 01 00 45 00 1 5570.322
2013 12 01 01 00 00 1 5570.344
2013 12 01 01 15 00 1 5570.365
2013 12 01 01 30 00 1 5570.381
2013 12 01 01 45 00 1 5570.398
2013 12 01 02 00 00 1 5570.407
```

I have shown a sample of data above. The last two columns are a constant number `1` and the height.  As you can see, it has white spaces making it difficult for me to use `datetime` module in python.

Comment: what is "1 5570.251"? miliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to break a long string of data into rows before you parse the date and height information. Since all of the data seems to be of the same length, this code should work:

```
data = "2013 12 01 00 00 00 1 5570.251 2013 12 01 00 15 00 1 5570.276 2013 12 01 00 30 00 1 5570.300 2013 12 01 00 45 00 1 5570.322 2013 12 01 01 00 00 1 5570.344 2013 12 01 01 15 00 1 5570.365 2013 12 01 01 30 00 1 5570.381 2013 12 01 01 45 00 1 5570.398 2013 12 01 02 00 00 1 5570.407"

for i in xrange(0, len(data), 31):
   row = data[i:i+31]
   t = row[:19]
   h = row[20:]
   d = datetime.strptime(t, "%Y %m %d %H %M %S")   
   print "DATE:", d, "  HEIGHT:", h
```

If some of the data ends up being a different length (e.g. if the height is not always 8 chars) then you will need to parse the original data to split the string after every 8th space instead. The above it easier to read, but assumes that your data is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your last numbers mean, but you can put the whitespaces in the format string to handle them.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> data = ...
>>> [(datetime.datetime.strptime(data[i:i+22],"%Y %m %d %H %M %S 1 "),data[i+22:i+30]) for i in range(len(data))[::31]]

[(datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 0, 0), '5570.251'),
 (datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 0, 15), '5570.276'),
  ...
(datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 2, 0), '5570.407')]
```

that will give you a list of tuples, each tuple contains datetime object, and the corresponding height

Comment: hi...been able to figure out with single data input....struggling with time series...forexample if i have 20 time stamps at interval of say 15 minutes.... #yr  mo dy hr mn  s -        m
2013 12 01 00 00 00 1 5570.251
2013 12 01 00 15 00 1 5570.276
2013 12 01 00 30 00 1 5570.300
2013 12 01 00 45 00 1 5570.322
2013 12 01 01 00 00 1 5570.344
2013 12 01 01 15 00 1 5570.365
2013 12 01 01 30 00 1 5570.381
2013 12 01 01 45 00 1 5570.398
2013 12 01 02 45 00 1 5570.420....also sorry but am new to stackoverflow so no idea how to post it properly.

Comment: explain better in the question